# Can't store value in database column datetime type in MySQL-PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I wanna save and store date format from $interval in database column which have dattime type. But its not work, in database not show that value.

```
 if ($no > 1){
     $startdate = new DateTime($lup[$no]);
     $enddate = new DateTime($lup[$no-1]);
     $int = $startdate->diff($enddate);
     $interval = $int->format("%d days, %h hours, %i minutes, and %s seconds &nbsp;");
     echo "<td>".$interval."&nbsp;</td>";
    }else
    {
     echo "<td> --- </td>&nbsp;";
    }

 if ($data['id'] == 2){
  $sql = mysql_query("
  INSERT INTO sla (booking_id, approval)
  VALUES ('$booking_id[$no]', '$interval')")
 ;}
```

Comment: You need to provide more information. Where is your code that adds the information to the database? See this page for assistance: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Add a code where you are inserting data into table.

Comment: Thanks for attention. I am already add that code @kmoser, jack

Comment: Thanks for attention. I am already add that code @Jack

Comment: Assuming ``$interval`` contains the data you want to insert into the ``approval`` column, you will need to reformat it to ``DATETIME`` format. Aside from the obvious problem of it currently being in the wrong format, you're trying to store an interval (difference) in a column that stores an absolute datetime, so this won't really work.

Comment: Thank you. So, what should i do? Just format it again to DATETIME? @kmoser

Comment: what makes you think you can store `"%d days, %h hours, %i minutes, and %s seconds &nbsp;"` into a datetime column?  You would need a varchar for that string, not datetime. I think the db is doing its job correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
if ($no > 1){
    $startdate = new DateTime($lup[$no]);
    $enddate = new DateTime($lup[$no-1]);
    $int = $startdate->diff($enddate);
    $interval = $int->format("%d days, %h hours, %i minutes, and %s seconds &nbsp;");
    $dtInterval = $int->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    echo "<td>".$interval."&nbsp;</td>";
   }else
   {
    echo "<td> --- </td>&nbsp;";
   }

if ($data['id'] == 2){
 $sql = mysql_query("
 INSERT INTO sla (booking_id, approval)
 VALUES ('$booking_id[$no]', '$dtInterval')")
;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if ($no > 1){
    $startdate = new DateTime($lup[$no]);
    $enddate = new DateTime($lup[$no-1]);
    $int = $startdate->diff($enddate);
    $interval = $int->format("%d days, %h hours, %i minutes, and %s seconds &nbsp;");
    echo "<td>".$interval."&nbsp;</td>";
   }else
   {
    echo "<td> --- </td>&nbsp;";
   }

if ($data['id'] == 2){
 $sql = mysql_query("
 INSERT INTO sla (booking_id, approval)
 VALUES ('".$booking_id[$no]."', '".$interval."')")
;}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `$interval` value is a string. If you want to store the data in that format then you should change the data type of your **approval** column from your **sla** table into **varchar** instead of **datetime**.